# Laravel - Change created_at to use unix timestamp

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working on Laravel 4 application and would like to save the unix timestamp for the created_at and updated_at fields instead of the default timestamp values.

Any suggestions on  how I could achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: do you need `created_at` column as it is? i mean if the column name is changed then?

Comment: i want to save the unix_timestamp values in the created_at and updated_at field actually, the column name does not pose a problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can just get the timestamp property, as:

```
$timestamp = $model->created_at->timestamp;
```

or, you could override the [getDateFormat()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps), and create migration of required fields, as:

```
$table->integer('created_at');
$table->integer('updated_at');
```

Comment: Thanks DemoUser!, overriding the getDateDateFormat() to return 'U' sets the created_at and updated_at to save the unix timestamp. values. Cheers!

Comment: what, it sounds like you answered your own question with your comment? This could be expanded upon a bit. Becaue just setting it as an integer doesnt seem to work (it causes an insert error).

Comment: @maximus69 isn't it `getDateFormat()` instead of `getDateDateFormat()`?